# Trying to permenantly remove an activity once I go back

Tags: android, memory, android-activity

When I launch an activity B from the main activity A and then go back, the activity should be removed. That is not the case, though. When I launch B from A again, I see that something stayed behind.

I am using systrace to compare the result from the first B run and second B run. I see less processing power on the second B run. activityStart and inflation times are highly reduced. The rendering response is 2/3 of the original response.

I have tried adding finish() on both `onStop()` and `onPause()` of activity B. Also, in the Intent starting the B activity, I added the flag to prevent the activity from being stored on the stack. On the manifest, I have added  `android:noHistory="true"` on activity B. I even tried calling the GC manually. Nothing really helps.

The only way that I can reset the B activity is to close the app completely. How do I remove activity B completely including any cached content that stays behind when I go back to the main activity?

Comment: You can start activity B with startActivityForResult function,

Comment: That does not help. Thanks, though.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running B activity as soon as you come back to A?

In terminal, run
`adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run`

```
authority=x.y.z.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider
    Running activities (most recent first):
        Run #1: ActivityRecord{B_Activity t6}
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{A_Activity t6}
```

`finish()` B_Activity, and go back to A_Activity.

```
authority=x.y.z.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider
    Running activities (most recent first):
        Run #1: ActivityRecord{A_Activity t6}
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{B_Activity t6 f}
```

You still can see, B_Activity even you finish it.

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with what OP asked, as far as I can see...sorry.

Comment: I have a button on activity A that launches activity B.